# Определение языка браузера и отображение нужной страницы

Tags: javascript

Как определить язык браузера пользователя и отобразить ему нужную страницу.
Есть 5 языковых версий сайта в HTML
Нужно реализовать логику редиректа на страницы
Подскажите как такое сделать через js

Comment: [navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)

Comment: @andreymal
Добавил ответ нижу от себя, редикерт работает но при при изменении языка страницы принудительно он все равно срабатывает :( 
Не подскажешь как переделать?

Comment: "он все равно срабатывает" : если не нужно чтобы срабатывал - перед switch вставить условие if (languageFistTwo!=currentLocation)

Comment: @PoulWWJD
Типу такого?
if (languageFistTwo!=currentLocation){ witch(some code){}}

в if засунуть swith?

Comment: @PoulWWJD
Если я правильно понял то не работает :( 

if(languageFistTwo  != currentLocation){
   switch (languageFistTwo){

   }
}

Comment: проверьте наличие искомого атрибута в своем теге html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Poul_WWJD/rqezchLy/

Comment: @PoulWWJD
 
Добавил верстку ссылок, по клику оно должно переходить на выбраную страницу, но все равно редиректит на англ добавив условие(
https://codepen.io/artur-alexandrowich/pen/KKNPemy

Comment: потому что тега html там по прежнему нет, и currentLocation не вычисляется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119039/discussion-between---and-poul-wwjd).

Comment: @PoulWWJD
У меня есть 5 страниц на разных языках, по логике которую ты описал оно должно работать, но при переходе на другую страницу оно все равно делает редирект на англ. у каждой страницы прописано <html lang="en-US" lang-js="en"></html>
<html lang="tr-TR" lang-js="tr"></html>
и т.д

Comment: не может ли быть проблема в конструкции switch?
ибо он  отрабатывает при каждой загрузке и опять отправляет на новую загрузку.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите в объекте *navigator* свойства *language* или *userLanguage*.

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

Comment: как выглядит условие редиректа на js, не подскажешь?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let language = window.navigator.language;
let languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,2); // To only keep the first 2 characters.
let currentLocation = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang-js')

switch (languageFistTwo) { 
  case "en":
   if(currentLocation != 'en'){
      window.location.href = 'index_en.html';
   }
    break;

  case "sv":
     if(currentLocation != 'sv')
   window.location.href = 'index_sa.html';
    break;

  case "tr":
     if(currentLocation != 'tr')
   window.location.href = 'index_tr.html';
    break;

  case "uk":
     if(currentLocation != 'uk')
   window.location.href = 'index_ua.html';
    break;

  default:
     if(currentLocation != 'ru'){
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
     }
}
```